# Using predicates on an array controller to filter related objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have an application using Core Data and bindings.  I want to have an NSSearchField that can search through an NSArrayController bound to an NSTableView.  The array controller contains Core Data objects that have a "name" field.  I have setup the NSSearchField like this:

```
Bind To: the array controller
Controller Key: filterPredicate
Predicate Format: name contains[c] $value
```

This works.  I want to extend it so that it can search to the fields of objects related to those in the array controller.  Each object in the array controller has a to-many relationship to another type of object called "tag" which has a field called "name".  I tried the following:

```
Bind To: the array controller
Controller Key: filterPredicate
Model Key Path: tags
Predicate Format: name contains[c] $value
```

This however does not work.  Nothing happens in the NSTableView when text is input into the NSSearchField.  What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Binding to `tags` as the model key path attempts to bind the search field predicate to the key path arrayController.filterPredicate.tags. Since the filterPredicate property of the array controller doesn't have a tags property, you're probably gettings 'key not found' exceptions that are being logged silently. Instead, recalling that the filterPredicate of an NSArrayController is applied to the members of the array, you want the binding to be set up something like this:

```
Bind To: <array controller>
Controller Key: filterPredicate
Predicate Format: ANY self.tags contains[c] $value
```

`self.tags` could be written as just `tags`, but I think this makes it clearer that tags is a property of the object to which the predicate is being applied.

Comment: I used as my predicate format: self.tags.name contains[c] $value

And I get an error:
Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = {(
    "A B C",
    "X Y Z",
)} rhs = A)

I think this is because the left hand side is a container.  How do I get it to be a string if there is more than one tag object?

Comment: guys how this worked!!
I have the same issue and it's not working. Barry, does the <array controller> is the same that hold the parent objects or it's another derived one??